# PHP отключение пользователя, прерывает ли работу скрипта?

Tags: php

Допустим есть скрипт:

```
<?php

sleep(5);

$db->query(запрос);
```

Так вот, если я зайду на нужную страницу, и данный скрипт запустится, но я до истечения 5ти секунд закрою вкладку, выполнится ли он до конца?

Читал про `ignore_user_abort`, но не совсем понял, так как там идёт описание только  про **терминал**.

> При работе с PHP-скриптом в командной строке, когда терминал скрипта
>   отключается без прерывания работы скрипта, скрипт будет остановлен,
>   если параметр value не равен TRUE

Comment: По всей видимости нет, скрипт продолжит работу. Об этом говорит само наличие функции `connection_aborted()`.

Comment: @Аникин вы можете прописать под функцией `sleep(10);` функцию `file_put_contents('File_name.txt', 'Строка для записи');`, потом запустить ваш файл в браузере, и не дожидаясь выполнения скрипта - закрыть браузер. Если по истечении 10 секунд с момента запуска скрипта, в директории с вашим запускаемым появится текстовый файл, то ответ на ваш вопрос будет положительным.

Comment: А нет, я ошибся. Прошу прощения. По-умолчанию скрипт прерывается, но это поведение можно поменять в `php.ini`. http://php.net/manual/ru/features.connection-handling.php

Answer (score 2):

Из документации на php.net:

> По умолчанию скрипт **завершает** свою работу при отключении клиента. Это поведение может быть изменено при помощи опции `ignore_user_abort` в конфигурационном файле `php.ini`. Такого же результата можно добиться, указав php_value ignore_user_abort в конфигурационном файле Apache `httpd.conf` или воспользовавшись функцией `ignore_user_abort()`.

Источник: http://php.net/manual/ru/features.connection-handling.php

Answer (score 1):

Информация к настройке ignore_user_abort в php.ini говорит нам о том, что если включить данный параметр, прерывание связи с клиентом не повлияет на выполнение скрипта, он будет завершен.

Так что делаем вывод, что отключение клиента - прерывает запущенный им скрипт, если опция не включена.

> ; If enabled, the request will be allowed to complete even if the user
>   aborts ; the request. Consider enabling it if executing long requests,
>   which may end up ; being interrupted by the user or a browser timing
>   out. PHP's default behavior ; is to disable this feature. ;
>   http://php.net/ignore-user-abort ;ignore_user_abort = On